# Scaling the Training set

Tags: python

I'm trying to scale my training set, using the following Python script:

```
sc = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
training_set_scaled = sc.fit_transform(training_set)
```

Then I encounter the following error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '10.152.152.11'
```

How could I resolve this error?

Comment: Change the code where the string `'10.152.152.11'` is passed to the `float()` function, or prevent that the string `'10.152.152.11'` reaches this code.

Comment: If you provide an example of your input data it would be easier to identify the solution here. What format is your input data? Are there non-numeric columns, or just the occasional invalid value that needs cleaning?

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering suggests that there are non-numeric (string) values in your training_set, and the 'MinMaxScaler' is trying to convert them to float values, which is not possible for strings. To resolve this issue, you need to preprocess your data to ensure that it contains only numeric values before using the 'MinMaxScaler'.

Remove or convert non-numeric values: Depending on the nature of your data, you can choose to either remove rows or columns containing non-numeric values or convert them into appropriate numeric representations (e.g., replacing IP addresses with numerical features).

```
# Drop rows containing non-numeric values
training_set = training_set.dropna().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: I tried it, it gives me this error: AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'drop'

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to scale all of your data, but some of your features are not numeric, or cannot be coerced into numeric type, so you are getting an error.

You have a couple of options here. You could subset your training data first just apply the the MinMaxScaler transformation to the numeric columns.

You could also use a column transformer approach (adapted from [the docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/compose/plot_column_transformer_mixed_types.html)):

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

numeric_features = ["feature_1", "feature_2"]
numeric_transformer = Pipeline(
    steps=[("scaler", MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1)))]
)


)
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ("num", numeric_transformer, numeric_features),
    ]
)

training_set_transformed = preprocessor.fit_transform(training_set)
```

This is particularly useful if you want to apply multiple transformations to multiple data types.

Note the above example assumes you have a DataFrame with column names, but you can also pass integers for the index values of your numeric types, if your data is in a different format.